# Insert into multiple tables from one form (mysql and PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, insert, transactions

I'm new to this site and coding so please go easy on me if you come across some rookie mistakes.

I have a single form that when submitted it inserts data into two separate tables (users, users_addresses). The user address should be linked back to the user by the User's ID.

I have seen a couple different methods that can be used for this type of problem (and none which IC an get to work), but I'm reaching out for help to see which would be the best way.

This is what I have so far:

```
public function createNewUser($details, $active) 
{
    $password  = $details["password"];
    $username  = strtolower($details["username" ]);
    $firstname = strtolower($details["firstname"]);
    $lastname  = strtolower($details["lastname" ]);
    $email     = strtolower($details["email"    ]);
    $sex       = strtolower($details["sex"      ]);
    $datepicker  = strtolower($details["datepicker" ]);
    $disabled  = ($active) ? "0" : "1";
    $address1     = strtolower($details["address1"    ]);
    $address2     = strtolower($details["address2"    ]);
    $province     = strtolower($details["province"    ]);
    $city     = strtolower($details["city"    ]);
    $district     = strtolower($details["district"    ]);
    $zipcode     = strtolower($details["zipcode"    ]);


    $

    $sql       = "INSERT INTO users VALUES (NULL, LOWER('$username'), MD5('$password'), LOWER('$firstname'), LOWER('$lastname'), LOWER('$email'), LOWER('$sex'), LOWER('$datepicker'), 0, NOW(), $disabled, 0)";

    $resultSet = $this->db->query($sql);
    return $this->db->getInsertId();

    $sql      = "INSERT INTO users_addresses VALUES (NULL, LOWER('$userid'), LOWER('$address1'), LOWER('$address2'), LOWER('$province'), LOWER('$city'), LOWER('$district), LOWER('$zipcode')";
    $resultSet = $this->db->query($sql);
    return $this->db->getInsertId();
 }
```

Comment: You want to make the value in lower case so much. You first use `strtolower` in PHP, then use `LOWER()` in MySQL query. Strange.

Comment: as lower as possible lol :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second query is never executed as you have a return statement before it executing in all conditions. Even if that is corrected, $user_id in second query has not been filled with value obtained from first query. Solution is below:

First

```
return $this->db->getInsertId();
```

should be replaced by

```
$user_id=$this->db->getInsertId();
```

Second

```
return $this->db->getInsertId();
```

should be replaced by

```
return $user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

There is quite something wrong / strange with your code:

1. Don't put variables directly in SQL code, use [prepared statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead.
2. You are calling `strtolower` and `LOWER` on all the data. No need to do it twice.
3. The second query is never done, because you `return` before it. That's "unreachable code".

The fix is probably done by replacing the first `return $this->db->getInsertId()` with `$userid = $this->db->getInsertId()` and the second one with `return $userid`.

Good luck and welcome to SO.